# C# Ninject to Structure map converter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, structuremap

In `ninject` I have code like this:

```
var resourceManagers = new ResourceManager[1];
resourceManagers[0] = Validation.ResourceManager;
kernel.Bind<ILocalizedStringProvider>().To<ResourceStringProvider>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("resourceManager", resourceManagers);

kernel.Rebind<ModelValidatorProvider>().To<LocalizedModelValidatorProvider>();
```

I want to convert this to `StructureMap`

I did like this:

```
IContainer container = new Container();
var ioC = new IoC();
ioC.Initialize(container);

container.Configure(x =>
{

    var resourceManagers = new ResourceManager[1];
    resourceManagers[0] = ModelValidation.ResourceManager;
    x.For<ILocalizedStringProvider>().Use<ResourceStringProvider>.Ctor<string>(@"resourceManager").Is(resourceManagers);
    x.For<ModelValidatorProvider>().Add<LocalizedModelValidatorProvider>();
});

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
```

but I get exception:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0119  'CreatePluginFamilyExpression.Use()'
>   is a method, which is not valid in the given context

How to do this with `StructureMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use () because is a method

```
var resourceManagers = new ResourceManager[1];
resourceManagers[0] = ModelValidation.ResourceManager;

x.For<ILocalizedStringProvider>().Use<ResourceStringProvider>().Ctor<ResourceManager[]> (@"resourceManager").Is(resourceManagers);
x.For<ModelValidatorProvider>().Add<LocalizedModelValidatorProvider>();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, this:

`.Use<ResourceStringProvider>`

Should be:

`.Use<ResourceStringProvider>()`

Because it is a method.